# Error result would be too long a vector

Tags: r, function, prime-factoring

I was trying to write a function that would show the prime factors of a number. This is what I got

```
unipri<- function (n) {
    q<- NULL
    for (i in 1:n){if (n%%i==0)  p<- c(p, i) }
    q<- c(1 ,apply(as.matrix(p), 1,function(c) ifelse(all(c%%(2:(c-1))!=0),c,1)))
    q<- q[!duplicated(q)]
    return (q)
}
```

when I give it a value like: 600851475143, I get an error massage

> "Error in 1:n : result would be too long a vector"

Any suggestion, also it there more compact way to write the code?

Comment: If you just want to get the prime factors there are already functions in packages that will do that. If your goal is to write the algorithm yourself there are more efficient ways to do the task than what you have.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I want to write the algorithm myself. Any suggestion what should I change to make it more efficient?

Comment: The code doesn't work as it is. You need to define p before concatenating with i in the second line of your function.

Comment: If you want to do arithmetic with very large integers, have a look at the `gmp` package.  Also, in your loop, you only need `i` to go from 1 to the square root of n.

Answer (score 2):

A more efficient way of factorising is to do it recursively.  Here is an example.

```
factorise <- function(a,n){ #need 'a' as a cumulative answer in order to retain on recursion.  Initially null.
  if(n<4){
    a <- c(n,a)
  } else {
    maxtest <- floor(sqrt(n)) #highest possible divisor
    odds <- floor(maxtest/2) #number of odd factors to test
    totest <- c(2,2*seq_len(odds)+1) #list of possible factors
    i <- 1
    fac <- FALSE
    while(!fac & i<=length(totest)){
      fac <- (n %% totest[i] == 0) #found a divisor
      if(fac) a <- Recall(c(totest[i],a),n/totest[i]) #recursive bit
      i <- i+1
    }
    if(!fac) a <- c(n,a)
  }
  return(a)
}

factors <- function(n) {
  sort(factorise(numeric(0),n))
}

factors(600851475143)
[1]   71  839 1471 6857
```